# Web-Application Design: users, account. database strucure and architecture

Tags: web-applications

Hy,

In my application there will be: 
profiles: they are just users that make a profile and can do a lot of stuff...
businesses: they can make new ads and do all this stuff

both can login and a profile can be a business to and here is the problem!
I was thinking in doing an accunt table, that stores the email and password and the types of account.. but is not so solid this approach

You have a better idea? thanks

Comment: I would like to hear why you think that your proposed approach is *not so solid*.

Comment: because i have a field in the accounts db like this: default_type = 'profile' and then a default_types = 'profile, business'
In my oppinion this is not so solid for a large app.

Comment: It would be easier for people to recommend a good solution if you stated which programming language and framework you intend to use. In asp.net, for example, a lot of this is already part of the framework, so you would have something to look at and build on top of.

Comment: Im using Ruby on rails with a Mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some websites have a `User` table and a `Role` table and a `UserRole` table. The content shown to each visitor is then based on which roles the user belongs to. But there are several other ways to do this.